# Bootstrap - how to achieve a custom-select with a larger height while with the same height as form-control-lg?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am with Bootstrap 4.3.1, and need to make the size of a custom-select to have the same height as form-control-lg.

When I set it `<select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="inputAircraftSupervising" name='inputAircraftSupervising'></select>` it has a default height and fill up the width of the parent div. This is good. 
[image]

When I set it `<select class="custom-select-lg mr-sm-2" id="inputAircraftSupervising" name='inputAircraftSupervising'></select>` it is changed to a larger height but the width shrinks to the default width of a form-control.
[image]

How can I achieve the same width (fill up the width of the page) while still with a larger height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the "custom-select" and the "custom-select-lg" as class of the select together (but with the custom-select before custom-select-lg). Here the code:

```
<select class="custom-select custom-select-lg mr-sm-2" id="inputAircraftSupervising" name='inputAircraftSupervising'></select>
```

I made a test on bootply and work very well for me: https://www.bootply.com/GWDJRvtp3I